# No module named 'bankdate'(How to import just .py??)

Tags: python, python-import

Sorry that I have no idea how to describe this situation. The bigger package I like to install is "finance" (http://pydoc.net/finance/0.2502/finance.bankdate/). I downloaded it and unzipped to install using `python setup.py install`.

However, I cannot resolve importing another sub-module

> bankdate(.py)

When I use finance module, there comes the error message, `"ImportError: No module named 'bankdate'`.(It is required in `"__init__.py"` under finance.)  `bankdate.py` seems to be file under finance folder. How could I install "bankdate"?? Does anybody help me with this??

Thank you~!

cf) `pip install bankdate`, `easy_install bankdate` don't work in this case.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? This may be an absolute versus relative import issue that would only work in Python 2.

Comment: @Evert Yes I'm using python 3.5 which is virtual environment under Anaconda. Is this make difference?

Comment: This package does not support Python 3.

Comment: Wow, that is a information Thanks, user2357112

Comment: Yes, Python 3 doesn't handle imports the same way Python 2 does. You have a few options: 1/ Use Python 2, 2/ ask the author to fix the imports, 3/ fix the imports yourself, and re-install the package. Given the last update is from 2014, I'm doubtful point 2/ will work though.

Comment: @Evert, I'll give it a try. Thank you so much for your comment:)

Comment: it doesn't work under python2.7 either, thanks anyway

Comment: It should work under Python 2. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I cannot import `EventFinder`, `SampleConditions`, `MultipleEvent`. I'm using `from finance import EventFinder, SampleConditions, MultipleEvents`. Do I install it correctly? There is a red line.

Comment: What is *the error*? Give the actual error. Also, this seems to be a different error than your original one.

Comment: @Evert oh, it seems to be chaning name and uploaded in github. https://github.com/danielfrg/PythonFinance  But how could I install this? it regards to sub folder event(event study)

Comment: Where in the world do you find `EventFinder`, `Sampleconditions` or `MultipleEvent`. I can't find *any* of these in the source code or installed package.

Comment: @Evert it is in https://github.com/danielfrg/PythonFinance/tree/master/events. I'm just following the examples shown in the web so I could use EventFinder etc.

Comment: Sorry, if you're going to swap packages mid-way, all bets are off; please close the current question if you're not interested anymore in solving it. You're own on your own; good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are working with Linux or Windows. But it would be a good start checking if the package was installed properly. You could use the following code to check installed packages and its versions:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

By doing so packages installed using both `setuptools` and `pip` will appear in a list below. If your package does not appear in the list there you have, it was not installed. 
Neverhteless try to import the module usign this:

```
from finance import bankdate
```

And see if the error continue. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm working with Windows. I'm currently trying python2.x. Thank you for commenting:)

Answer (score -1):

you can use pip install finance or you can download .whl file use pip intsall .whl
you can try